# What type is the next variable?

Tags: c++

So I had this question at an exam. And I don't know which answer is correct.

```
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct Test{
    int note;
    char exam[20];
}qwerty;

int main()
{
    cout<<qwerty.exam;
}
```

What is the type of qwerty.exam in the previous code? Is it char or char[20]?
They said the right answer is char[20]. But if the type is char[20], why can't I declare something like: char[20] exam; ?

Moreover, I found this on cplusplus website:
Like a regular variable, an array must be declared before it is used. A typical declaration for an array in C++ is:

type name [elements];

where type is a valid type (such as int, float...), name is a valid identifier and the elements field (which is always enclosed in square brackets []), specifies the length of the array in terms of the number of elements.

**So I understand that the type does not depend on the number of elements. Please try to explain.
Thanks in advance!**

Comment: you forgot to mention c++20

Comment: @Teo The declaration of the variable exam is already written in your question char exam[20];. So it is unclear what is the problem.

Comment: The type of `exam` is  `an array of 20 char`

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Just answer to my question please. What is the type of qwerty.exam in the previous code?

Comment: If you declare an array using the syntax posted the type depends on both the type and the size.

Comment: Correction to what you read on cplusplus:  `type_of_each_element name[count_of_the_elements];`

Comment: Thanks @Eljay . So the type is char[20], not just char.

Comment: cplusplus isnt known to be most accurate. When they say `type name [elements];` declares the array then they mean `type` is the type of the elements (not the type of the array). Btw, better add the link when you quote from elsewhere: https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But if the type is char[20], why can't I declare something like: char[20] exam; ?

That's not the correct syntax. The correct syntax is `char exam[20]`. You could also do something like this:

```
using char_array = char[20];
char_array exam;
```

> So I understand that the type does not depend on the number of elements.

That's exactly the opposite of what's the case. Arrays of different sizes have completely different types. Therefore, `char[20]` and `char[21]` are completely different types.